# Issue processing Spring MVC form with multiple dropdown menus

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a form with two dropdown menus to select a student and a course the student will take.  When I load the page with this form, I get errors that I will include below.

Here is my jsp form.

**assignStudent.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@include file="header.jsp"%>
<p>
<h2>Assign a Student to a Course</h2>
<br />
<form:form method="POST" action="/myApp/assignStudent">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>Course</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:select path="studentMap" items="${studentMap}">
            </form:select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:select path="courseMap" items="${courseMap}">
            </form:select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
</table>
</form:form>
</p>
<%@include file="footer.jsp"%>
```

Here is the relevant section of my controller class that I've been tinkering with:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/assignStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView enrollInCourse()
{
    Map<Integer, String> studentMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    //Create a map to put into the student dropdown menu
    for (Student s : studentDAO.allStudents())
    {
        String fullName = s.getFirstName() + " " + s.getLastName();

        studentMap.put(s.getStudentID(), fullName);
    }

    Map<Integer, String> courseMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    //Create a map to put into the course dropdown menu
    for (Course c : courseDAO.allCourses())
    {           
        courseMap.put(c.getCourseID(), c.getCourseName());
    }

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("assignStudent", "command", new StudentCourse());

    model.addObject("studentMap", studentMap);
    model.addObject("courseMap", courseMap);

    return model;
}
```

Following is the error message I get:

> HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page
>   /WEB-INF/jsp/assignStudent.jsp at line 14
>
> type Exception report
>
> message An exception occurred processing JSP page
>   /WEB-INF/jsp/assignStudent.jsp at line 14
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
>   JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/assignStudent.jsp at line 14

```
 11:    </tr> 
 12:    <tr> 
 13:        <td> 
 14:            <form:select path="studentMap" items="${studentMap}"> 
 15:            </form:select> 
 16:        </td>
 17:        <td>
```

> Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'studentMap' of bean class [com.myapp.StudentCourse]: Bean
>   property 'studentMap' is not readable or has an invalid getter method:
>   Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the
>   setter?
>     org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:726)
>     org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:717)
>     org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
>     org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:229)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:120)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag.writeTagContent(SelectTag.java:194)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.assignStudent_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fselect_005f0(assignStudent_jsp.java:267)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.assignStudent_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(assignStudent_jsp.java:218)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.assignStudent_jsp._jspService(assignStudent_jsp.java:122)    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

I'm pretty new to Spring MVC so I appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show the StudentCourse class but according to the root exception

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'studentMap' of bean class [com.myapp.StudentCourse]: Bean property 'studentMap' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Your StudentCourse class does not have a `studentMap` property, or it's either missing it's setter or it's named something other than `setStudentMap` so the solution would be to add a studentMap property to your class and write a setter and a getter following the proper naming rules (`setStudentMap` and `getStudentMap`).

If, however, you do not wish to have a studentMap property in your StudentCourse class you can use the [public ModelAndView(View view,
                    java.util.Map model)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#ModelAndView-org.springframework.web.servlet.View-java.util.Map-) constructor and pass your StudentCourse, studentMap and courseMap objects with that.